# Extract column which maximize variable under condition in R

Tags: r

I would like to select the column from data(mtcars) where the qsec is maximum, under the condition that the number of cylinders is higher or equal to 8.

I tried the max function, but then I only get the max value of qsec and not the entire column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be able to uset [`which.max`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/which.min) to get the location of the maximum.  It would be easier to help if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you mean to get the row where `cyl >= 8` and `qsec` is maximum.

```
subset(mtcars, cyl >= 8 & qsec == max(qsec[cyl >= 8]))

#             mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Merc 450SLC 15.2   8  276 180 3.07 3.78   18  0  0    3    3
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% filter(cyl >= 8 & qsec == max(qsec[cyl >= 8]))
```